# HTML, JS How to play/stop video on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, video

As you can see I have a question about playing/stoping video on hover. The user would hover the mouse on video and it would start playing and when he move the mouse away video would stop playing. Is it possible and how? I have video tag here

```
<video id="video" controls="" loop="" src="/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/vid/elipsiniai-treniruokliai.mp4" width="auto" height="auto" alt=""></video>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update**

A fix is added for the error that was thrown in the console when hovering over the videos (tested in chrome)

> Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first.

adding `muted="muted"` attribute to the video tag fixes the problem. For details see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49930680/how-to-handle-uncaught-in-promise-domexception-play-failed-because-the-use)

---

Here you go

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".myvideos").on("mouseover", function(event) {
    this.play();

  }).on('mouseout', function(event) {
    this.pause();

  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<video class="myvideos" controls="" loop="" src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4" width="auto" height="auto" alt="" muted="muted"></video>
<video class="myvideos" controls="" loop="" src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4" width="auto" height="auto" alt="" muted="muted"></video>
<video class="myvideos" controls="" loop="" src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4" width="auto" height="auto" alt="" muted="muted"></video>
<video class="myvideos" controls="" loop="" src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4" width="auto" height="auto" alt="" muted="muted"></video>
```

Comment: Your works, but oposite way. When I move mouse away it plays video

Comment: you want it the other way around?

Comment: Yes. I need that it would play on hover

Comment: Thank you! And one last think. What I need to change so I could make this code work for every video on the same website page and not only on one?

Comment: you should assign a separate `class` to all the `video tags` and initialize it with `class` rather than `id`, that way you can `initialize` all the videos with this functionality rather than adding all the ids separately.

Comment: i have updated my answer , to your requirements, check it now it has multiple videos @NeimantasJocius

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$("#video").hover(
    ()=>{ $(this).get(0).play(); },
    ()=>{ $(this).get(0).pause(); }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

To make a video play/pause on hover, try this:

JS:

```
var figure = $(".video").hover(hoverVideo, hideVideo);

function hoverVideo(e) {
    $('video', this).get(0).play();
}

function hideVideo(e) {
    $('video', this).get(0).pause();
}
```

CSS:

```
video::-webkit-media-controls {
    display:none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For this you have to use javascript. Easiest would be some kind of implementation with jQuery/javascript implementation.

You could also find this easily on the internet, this took me 3 seconds just by typing the "video on hover" in google: https://codepen.io/gil--/pen/bNxZWg

Html:

```
<div id="videosList">           
<div class="video">
    <video class="thevideo" loop preload="none">
      <source src="https://giant.gfycat.com/VerifiableTerrificHind.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
  </div>
</div>
```

You need to watch for hover event on video tag.

```
var figure = $(".video").hover( hoverVideo, hideVideo );
```

Now you add a function that plays video on hover:

```
function hoverVideo(e) {  
  $('video', this).get(0).play(); 
}
```

And when user leaves the video you add another function:

```
function hideVideo(e) {
  $('video', this).get(0).pause(); 
}
```