# How to fix "Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first." on Desktop with Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, video, html5-video

I have found this [solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49930680/how-to-handle-uncaught-in-promise-domexception-play-failed-because-the-use), it working for my system. But i got this issue in my wordpress website. They as suggesting to update Autoplay policy. I need to fix this on all computers. Any ideas?

Comment: I got the solution for muted videos with javascript code..
`jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery(".video_class_name").prop('muted', true); 
});`

Comment: Possible duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51041580/muted-autoplay-video-shows-error-play-failed-because-the-user-didnt-interact

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to handle "Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first." on Desktop with Chrome 66?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49930680/how-to-handle-uncaught-in-promise-domexception-play-failed-because-the-use)

Answer (score 4):

This may works. First mute the audio because browsers does not allow to auto play video with audio.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $(".video_class_name").prop('muted', true);
    $(".video_class_name")[0].play();
});
```