# Muted Autoplay video shows error: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first.

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, video, flowplayer, autoplay

I am trying to make an HTML5 video autoplay (in muted condition) in the popup in the page. The popup is hidden when page is loaded. When user tries to go out of page (from top), it shows video popup with AutoPlay & muted ON. Then I tried to play video with JavaScript but it gives this error: `play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first.`

It works fine if I click somewhere on page or if developer panel is open before the video popup is displayed. I am using Flow Player, and issue only in Google Chrome (works fine on FF).

Can you please give any ideas on how to overcome this?

Thanks, J

Answer (score 3):

Google Chrome has updated the autoplay policies.
[URL for reference](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes)

According to new behaviours:

1. Muted autoplay is always allowed.
2. Autoplay with sound is allowed if:

   - User has interacted with the domain (click, tap, etc.).
   - On desktop,the user's Media Engagement Index threshold has been crossed,
     meaning the user has previously play video with sound.
   - On mobile,the user has added the site to his or her home screen.
3. Top frames can delegate autoplay permission to their iframes to allow autoplay with sound.

Comment: Yes i Know muted autoplay is always allowed. And it's working fine if video is visible on page load. in my case video is in hidden state when page loads. when video visible and  I tried to play video with JavaScript it gives an error. @Paul

Comment: "play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first." from this error. This happens because of the chrome will allow any operations it stops only if "User has interacted with the domain (click, tap, etc.)."
Without any user, interaction chrome will not allow autoplay with sound according to the new privacy policy. I have also faced such issues now I play video with the muted option by default, and asks for user interaction for sound.

Comment: yes Right @Pual, I have same issue before that's why turn off sound. but in this case my video is in muted  by default. then why chrome gives me error.  Here is url of page : http://dev.artoonsolutions.com/dev-ewv/exit-popup/    userName: artoon ,  pass: Dev@Ar2N1#  to access site.

Comment: Are you asking about this error in your website? Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <, because I was able to see this error 3 times and a warning for a cache of the browser.

Comment: @Pual , no not that error. error will fire when you exit window from top video popup show. with the error i mention above in question.  before exit make sure close developer menu then  reload and try to exit window from top and then open developer menu and error shows up.

Comment: @Jignesh, On observing the issue the error happens when the popup flowplayer video tries to play, I hope the popup's flow player video is not properly muted.

on checking the video tags in your site i could see the following
$(document.querySelectorAll('video')[0]).prop('muted')
true
$(document.querySelectorAll('video')[1]).prop('muted')
false
$(document.querySelectorAll('video')[2]).prop('muted')
true

I GUESS POPUP FLOW PLAYER IS NOT MUTED.

Comment: Muted autoplay is not working here, and this is annoying as there is no way to reset the counter, which is a big issue when developing.