# Chromium - "Failed because the user didn't interact with the document first" in chrome?

Tags: web, video-streaming, html5-video, chromium, hls.js

Ok, autoplay on visit used to work on our site. However now, we are getting:

> play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first

How come autoplay works on Youtube though? For instance on open video in **new tab.**

Using HLS.js it no longer work.

What is Youtube doing that **we could do here**?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Muted Autoplay video shows error: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51041580/muted-autoplay-video-shows-error-play-failed-because-the-user-didnt-interact)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latest version of chrome creates a per domain “score” if a user has interacted with media 20 times on a domain, it is allowed to auto play. If the interaction score is lower, it can't. Chrome has a post about this on the developer blog.

Comment: does this apply on a localhost development website ?

Comment: only benefits big players