# Is there any way that Bitmovin Player can autoplay without muted?

Tags: javascript

I was trying to make the Bitmovin Player autoplay without muted. And the browser said it is not allowed. But Netflix and Amazon movie work. Just wondering is there anyway that can make the Bitmovin Player autoplay without muted? Thank you!

```
config = {
key: 'INSERTPROVIDEDKEYHERE',
playback: {
  autoplay: true,
  muted: false
},
source: {
  dash: 'https://path/to/mpd/file.mpd',
  hls: 'https://path/to/hls/playlist/file.m3u8',
  smooth: 'https://path/to/manifest/file/Manifest',
  progressive: [{
    url: 'http://path/to/mp4',
    type: 'video/mp4'
  }, {
    url: 'http://path/to/webm',
    type: 'video/webm'
  }],
  poster: 'images/poster.jpg',  
}}
```

The browser returned: "Playback could not be started, reason: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first."

Comment: Is this a problem on mobile devices in particular? or is it in any device?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro It's in any device.

Comment: Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51041580/3695983) and this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51043187/3695983). They have the same issue and they explain why it is not autoplaying without mute, linking to a [Google Docs reference](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes). This question could be considered a duplicate of those two.

Comment: Yeah, I've already checked them out. But Netflix and Amazon movie player seems to be able to autoplay any movie without muted. Do you know how they do that? Is there any way that bitmovin can do the same thing?

Comment: Read the linked [Google Docs reference](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes). It explains how autoplay with sound is only allowed after user interaction (not your case); or if the site has a high MEI (probably not your site, but the case of Netflix, Amazon, Youtube, et al. The link provides an explanation of the MEI and how it is calculated); or in certain cases on mobile. The main issue is that your site probably does not have enough media plays for Chrome to autoplay with sound.

Comment: I see. I think that solved my question. Thank you! Who don't you put your answer down there so that I can mark your answer solved the question?

Comment: @Novus it seems that Safari and Chrome carry a database of pre-blessed websites, which I assume include the likes of Youtube, Netflix etc. See https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/audio-video/autoplay/autoplay-pre-seeding-in-chrome and https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/90784

Comment: From https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/90784 for posterity: "Safari in macOS High Sierra uses differential privacy to algorithmically identify an up-to-date set of websites for which most users prefer auto-play with sound, such as popular video websites like Netflix, YouTube, and Twitch. Our algorithmic approach allows us infer auto-play policies worldwide, and is capable of identifying and adapting to trending new websites. Default site settings are updated regularly, generally coinciding with Safari update releases"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the linked Google Docs [blog](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes) [posts](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/11/web-audio-autoplay). It explains how autoplay with sound is only allowed after user interaction (not your case); or if the site has a high MEI (probably not your site, but the case of Netflix, Amazon, Youtube, et al. The link provides an explanation of the MEI and how it is calculated); or in certain cases on mobile. The main issue is that your site probably does not have enough media plays for Chrome to autoplay with sound. **– Alvaro Montoro**

Answer (score 0):

Bitmovin player fires event `ON_SOURCE_LOADED` after source loaded, so by listening this event, on next step you can play video.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try it out.

Answer (score 0):

That is an issue with newer browser versions to not autostart videos all the time and consume too much energy.

They also wrote a blog post about this https://bitmovin.com/play-not-play-new-autoplay-policies-safari-11-chrome-64/

Answer (score 0):

It seems Chrome [whitelists](https://blog.google/products/chrome/improving-autoplay-chrome/) some sites:

> If you don’t have browsing history, Chrome allows autoplay for over 1,000 sites where we see that the highest percentage of visitors play media with sound.

In case yours is not one of these sites, you will have to implement a hack, e.g. from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Autoplay_guide):

```
let playAttempt = setInterval(() => {
  videoElem.play()
    .then(() => {
      clearInterval(playAttempt);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log('Unable to play the video, User has not interacted yet.');
    });
}, 3000);
```