# Chrome not autoplaying muted video

Tags: html, typescript, google-chrome, video

I'm trying to autoplay a video, it works in safari and firefox but not in chrome. I have the muted attribute, I also tried to play it with typescript but get an error, something like: "Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first", I know it has something to do with the new politics of google, but what can I do to fix this bug?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a new Google policy, cf

- https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes
- and [Muted Autoplay video shows error: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51041580/muted-autoplay-video-shows-error-play-failed-because-the-user-didnt-interact)
- `document.getElementById('video1').play();`  After loading your video worked 6 months ago, seems not possible from now...

Answer (score 0):

I was caught up with the same problem initially. Earlier just the `autoplay` tag used to get the job done. Now its not the case. A simple tweak worked for me: `autoplay="true"` instead of just `autoplay`.

Fix

```html
<video autoplay="true" muted>
    <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```