# Slider does not load automatically

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

Home slider video is not loading automatically, it is always necessary to refresh the screen for it to execute. (This happens 90% of the time you access the WebSite, and especially in Chrome, very strange ...).

Another thing that works, is to slide the home to the footer and go back to the header. It's the video that runs.

Think of an html script, css, php, js that performs an automatic refresh in HOME, already at the beginning of loading.

I'm also testing plugin switching, WordPress downgrade, other alternatives, etc., but also other errors.

Any suggestions to make sure the video runs automatically?

Link for Home: http://www.grupomult.com.br/

Partition source code contains slider and video:

```
<div class="et_pb_section et_pb_section_video  et_pb_section_0 et_pb_with_background et_section_regular">


            <div class="et_pb_section_video_bg">

            <span class="mejs-offscreen">Tocador de vídeo</span><div id="mep_0" class="mejs-container mejs-container-keyboard-inactive mejs-video" tabindex="0" role="application" aria-label="Tocador de vídeo" style="width: 480px; height: 700px; min-width: 0px;"><div class="mejs-inner"><div class="mejs-mediaelement"><mediaelementwrapper id="mejs_4236248405640737"><video loop="loop" height="700" id="mejs_4236248405640737_html5" preload="none" src="http://www.grupomult.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/Grupo_Mult_v4_linha-1.mp4">
                <source type="video/mp4" src="http://www.grupomult.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/Grupo_Mult_v4_linha-1.mp4">

            </video></mediaelementwrapper></div><div class="mejs-layers"><div class="mejs-poster mejs-layer" style="display: none; width: 480px; height: 700px;"></div><div class="mejs-overlay mejs-layer" style="display: none; width: 480px; height: 700px;"><div class="mejs-overlay-loading"><span class="mejs-overlay-loading-bg-img"></span></div></div><div class="mejs-overlay mejs-layer" style="display: none; width: 480px; height: 700px;"><div class="mejs-overlay-error"></div></div><div class="mejs-overlay mejs-layer mejs-overlay-play" style="width: 480px; height: 700px;"><div class="mejs-overlay-button" role="button" tabindex="0" aria-label="Reproduzir" aria-pressed="false"></div></div></div><div class="mejs-controls"><div class="mejs-button mejs-playpause-button mejs-play"><button type="button" aria-controls="mep_0" title="Reproduzir" aria-label="Reproduzir" tabindex="0"></button></div><div class="mejs-time mejs-currenttime-container" role="timer" aria-live="off"><span class="mejs-currenttime">00:00</span></div><div class="mejs-time-rail"><span class="mejs-time-total mejs-time-slider" role="slider" tabindex="0" aria-label="Tempo do slider" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="NaN" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuetext="00:00"><span class="mejs-time-buffering" style="display: none;"></span><span class="mejs-time-loaded"></span><span class="mejs-time-current"></span><span class="mejs-time-hovered no-hover"></span><span class="mejs-time-handle"><span class="mejs-time-handle-content"></span></span><span class="mejs-time-float"><span class="mejs-time-float-current">00:00</span><span class="mejs-time-float-corner"></span></span></span></div><div class="mejs-time mejs-duration-container"><span class="mejs-duration">00:00</span></div><div class="mejs-button mejs-volume-button mejs-mute"><button type="button" aria-controls="mep_0" title="Mudo" aria-label="Mudo" tabindex="0"></button><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="mejs-volume-slider" aria-label="Controle de volume" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" role="slider" aria-orientation="vertical"><span class="mejs-offscreen">Use as setas para cima ou para baixo para aumentar ou diminuir o volume.</span><div class="mejs-volume-total"><div class="mejs-volume-current"></div><div class="mejs-volume-handle"></div></div></a></div><div class="mejs-button mejs-fullscreen-button"><button type="button" aria-controls="mep_0" title="Tela inteira" aria-label="Tela inteira" tabindex="0"></button></div></div></div></div>
        </div>
            <div class=" et_pb_row et_pb_row_0">


        <div class="et_pb_column et_pb_column_4_4  et_pb_column_0">

        <div class="et_pb_code et_pb_module  et_pb_code_0">

    </div> <!-- .et_pb_code -->
    </div> <!-- .et_pb_column -->
    </div> <!-- .et_pb_row -->

    </div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure what you're asking about, but will `<video controls autoplay>` help?

Comment: look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51041580/muted-autoplay-video-shows-error-play-failed-because-the-user-didnt-interact.

Comment: Thank you, in principle, its clarifications and the use of the plugin corrected the problem:

https://br.wordpress.org/plugins/videojs-html5-player/