# Store the user interaction with the page

Tags: javascript, html5-audio

I have an alert system web app, where if a new alert shows up, the app plays sound. But since there is this [Autoplay Policy](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes), the user must interact with a page first  if I want to play an audio on a page. I read a lot of SO questions about this issue, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49930680/how-to-handle-uncaught-in-promise-domexception-play-failed-because-the-use), but what I want is to store let say in `local storage` if user already interacted with page and play the audio automatically if he is a returning user. Since my users opens my web app frequently, they dont want to click on a button every time to allow playing notifications. Any idea how to achieve that?

Comment: A user can create a launcher which runs the program with appropriate flags or policy set to disable default browser policy.

Answer (score 1):

You need https connection for it. when users grant the permission once, its save and not ask again for that page. for more check https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/

Comment: That looks to address audio and video *input*, not *output*, which is entirely different. I can't remember *ever* having seen an audio permission request in Chrome or FF.

Comment: If the permissions are not required then program your sound to auto play or when you want to play.

Comment: Permissions *are* required, but IIRC it's always granted *implicitly*, via user interaction. Without user interaction, an error will be thrown - thus this question, the process seems very inconvenient.

Comment: This means that your browser don't save that permission state. try it with https then.

Comment: I remember running into this problem *on* HTTPS. I don't think HTTPS does anything here.

Comment: i guess it does. give a try at least once.