# Youtube player unmute function does not work inside an iframe

Tags: youtube-iframe-api

I have the youtube player autoplays MUTED inside an iframe and have an unmute button and I am calling unMute() on pressing the button. However I get this error:

```
Unmuting failed and the element was paused instead because the user didn't interact with the document before
```

Here the link to the page:

https://video.inpwrd.net/college-prep-dont-go-it-alone/48ebe783-bcc4-4b96-9ba5-aff3db5f13df

Outside iframe it works. This is definitely a bug because I am sticking to autoplay muted policy. This is the stack trace:

```
Unmuting failed and the element was paused instead because the user didn't interact with the document before

    g.h.xk  @   base.js:6951
    jya @   base.js:4586
    yQ  @   base.js:4585
    Fna @   base.js:3091
    g.h.unMute  @   base.js:6718
    a.F.(anonymous function)    @   base.js:3082
    g.h.handleExternalCall  @   base.js:6698
    a.C.(anonymous function)    @   base.js:3086
    (anonymous) @   www-embed-player.js:526
    k.la    @   www-embed-player.js:609
    k.La    @   www-embed-player.js:598
    ii.B    @   www-embed-player.js:594
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle "Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first." on Desktop with Chrome 66?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49930680/how-to-handle-uncaught-in-promise-domexception-play-failed-because-the-use)

Comment: No it is not. this only happens in iframe. Please read the details before flagging

Comment: allow="autoplay; fullscreen" on iframe fixed it