# Getting "play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first" error when trying to play sound (javascript/html)

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to play a sound on a web page using javascript but whenever I do, I get the above error. Here's my code:

```
if (thing.startsWith("0")) {
    var a = new Audio("audio.mp4");
    a.play();
}
```

Furthermore, if you open the console, the sound automatically starts playing.

Comment: Where is the error?

Comment: In the console.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle "Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first." on Desktop with Chrome 66?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49930680/how-to-handle-uncaught-in-promise-domexception-play-failed-because-the-use)

Comment: No, I mean you didn't include the error in the question, you said "I get the above error" but there is no error in the question.

Comment: @LeviBlodgett It's the title of the question.

Comment: OP, consider checking this out: [Autoplay Policy Changes](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes), which states *"Chrome's autoplay policies are simple: Muted autoplay is always allowed. Autoplay with sound is allowed if the user has interacted with the domain (click, tap, etc.)."*

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It´s because Google updated its Autoplay Policy, it is necessary for the user to make some interaction first with the window in which the sound will be played, for example a 'Start' button then you can play the sound. This happened because for many users it is annoying when a sound is played out of nowhere.

Comment: I know this is an old post, but it's kinda funny how Youtube is owned by Google and still to this day does not follow that policy.

Comment: @avisk, is the technique YouTube uses known? Some might try to investigate personally, but perhaps it's already shared.

Comment: "Some interaction" But there is no list on what that does mean, scrolling does not count, nor confirming alert, seems only click ?

Comment: @avisk I think it's built-in Chrome(ium) feature

Comment: @avisk based on this post https://developer.chrome.com/blog/autoplay/ it seems like they follow their own policy, even if it looks like an arbitrary one

Comment: @giorgio-tempesta [Media Engagement Index](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/autoplay/#media_engagement_index) threshold?

Comment: @SyndRain yes, precisely

Answer (score 6):

```
var resp = audio.play();

if (resp!== undefined) {
    resp.then(_ => {
        // autoplay starts!
    }).catch(error => {
       //show error
    });
}
```

This code helped me remove the warning form the console

Comment: You can find additional explanations on this snippet here: https://developer.chrome.com/blog/autoplay/