# my audio does not play on my hosted version of my site

Tags: javascript, html, css

The local version of my site will play my audio but when I upload it to the Cloudflare page it does not play

https://insane.rip (my site)

```
  if (event.keyCode == 32 && app.skippedIntro) {
    if (app.backgroundToggler) {
      app.videoElement.play();
      app.audioElement.play();
    } else {
      app.videoElement.play();
      app.audioElement.play();
    }
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Original Answer by [nat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11953400/nat) which you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58847289/15748278)

> It´s because Google updated its Autoplay Policy, it is necessary for
> the user to make some interaction first with the window in which the
> sound will be played, for example a 'Start' button then you can play
> the sound. This happened because for many users it is annoying when a
> sound is played out of nowhere.