# How to enable autoplay in html page. In chrome latest its not working

Tags: html, google-chrome

Team,

My code

```html
<audio autoplay id='myAudio' > 
     <source src="abc.mp3" type="audio/mp3">  
     <source src="abc.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">   
</audio>
```

As this was not working a function was called onload and mocked the event of clicking a button.
to  resolve the error "play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first"
My chrome build is 78.xx .  I know google have disabled this feature . I tried with iframe also but doesnt work. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50742427/8230810 suggests you need to add `muted` for autoplaying to work on Chrome 66+

Comment: sir this is for  audio tag  and not video tag Thanks

Comment: Probably the same problem though. Someone on that link suggests it's an intentional feature of Chrome to stop new tabs playing unprompted noise, so it's probably more of an audio thing on the video tags anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Google Chrome only allows you to use autoplay on the next scenarios:

- If `muted` is also added to the `audio` tag.
- User has interacted with the domain (click, tap, etc.)
- The user has added the site to their home screen on mobile or installed the PWA on desktop.

Chrome knows if the interaction is genuine or if it's mocked, so I don't suggest that way. My suggestion is make your website a PWA, or think a way to make the user interact with the website.

Source: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes

Comment: Thank you sir 1.unknown attribute muted says my editor when used with audio 2.That interaction is the problem here..here i want to  give some instructions on load

Comment: I think the problem nº1 is a problem of your editor. Here you have a working example: https://codepen.io/jhervas/pen/oNgvLGQ