# How to play audio on page Load or every set-interval in angular 6+

Tags: angular, audio, html5-audio

I need to Use audio sound on new requests based on business logic.
when I call "playAudio()" this function in Page Load Means NgOninit It's not working. it giving me the below error.

```
prescan-orderlist.component.ts:116 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first.
```

I search for that but based on crome new policy they have restricted.

Please help me if you have any idea to achieve this.

```js
public playAudio() {
    let audio = new Audio();
    audio.src = "../assets/images/beep.wav";
    audio.load();
    audio.play();

  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to handle "Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first." on Desktop with Chrome 66?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49930680/how-to-handle-uncaught-in-promise-domexception-play-failed-because-the-use)

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Chrome 66, pages can't play media automatically unless they are muted or the user starts the playback.

A page can start autoplay, but only with audio muted. You could set the `muted` property like this:

```
public playAudio() {
    let audio = new Audio();
    audio.src = "../assets/images/beep.wav";
    audio.muted = true;
    audio.load();
    audio.play();
}
```

However, since you are trying to play an audio file, not video, this will be pointless.