# How to make audio autoplay on chrome/ Firefox

Tags: html

i am facing difficulty in autoplay an audio in chrome/firefox browser on webpage load, it is working perfectly fine on microsoft edge/ Internet explorer witht the HTML5 Tag , but not working with chrome /mozilla, can anyone help me out?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50490304/how-to-make-audio-autoplay-on-chrome

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make audio autoplay on chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50490304/how-to-make-audio-autoplay-on-chrome)

Comment: Do you get any error on Chrome/Mozilla console?

Comment: @ShardulBirje Yes, Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first.

Comment: @Ameer Hamza Khan refer 
this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49930680/how-to-handle-uncaught-in-promise-domexception-play-failed-because-the-use

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
   <video autoplay>
      <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
```