# Play audio automatically in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to play audio automatically based on condition when I get ajax response. I receive `response.code == 1` from my ajax call, but it does not play the audio.

```html
<audio id="myAudio" >
  <source src="{{asset('Dashboard/alarm.mp3')}}" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

```js
$.ajax({
  url: '{{url('/')}}',
  type: 'POST',
  data: {
    _token: _token
  },
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(response) {
    if (response.code == 1) {
      playAudio();
    }
  }
});

function playAudio() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myAudio");
  x.play();
}
```

Comment: is the path to the music file correct?

Comment: Assuming the path to the file is correct, what happens when you add `console.log('playing')` to your PlayAudio function? Do you see `playing` in the console?

Comment: it says **Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first**

Comment: path is correct. If I use button and onclick event then it works

Comment: Ok, so the problem is the browser requires the user to do something with the page before it will allow audio to be played. One solution that might work is using this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54379573/3684265 triggering the play via `mousemove` event listener

Comment: add `x.load();` before `x.play();`

Comment: Still not working

Answer (score 0):

Browsers are often blocking sounds that are not triggered by user interaction, you can start playing the audio on the mouse move for example:

```
let isAjaxLoaded = false;

$(document).mousemove(function(){
  if (isAjaxLoaded) {
    playAudio();
  }
});

$.ajax({
  url: '{{url('/')}}',
  type: 'POST',
  data: {
    _token: _token
  },
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(response) {
    if (response.code == 1) {
      isAjaxLoaded = true;
    }
  }
});

function playAudio() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myAudio");
  x.play();
}
```

Comment: Still show Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first

Answer (score 0):

As @imvain2 mention is the comment, browsers won't allow to play the audio before user interaction. There is no way to hack this. This is to prevent page from annoying users. So to achieve this, we have to wait until user interaction. User clicks can be treated as user interaction. So add a event lister to window and implement your code there.

```
$.ajax({
  url: '{{url('/')}}',
  type: 'POST',
  data: {
    _token: _token
  },
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(response) {
    if (response.code == 1) {
      window.addEventListener('click', ()=> {
          playAudio();
      })
    }
  }
});

function playAudio() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myAudio");
  x.play();
}
```

**Not that, audio will play only after user clicks anywhere in the window.**