# Workaround on google's autoplay restriction

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-chrome, html5-audio, autoplay

I understand that google restricted the autoplay of video and audio features on google chrome and requires user interaction before playing audio. 
However, my app needs to play audio when I hover an image.

I've tried creating an invisible button and mimic a click event on my `@mousehover` event.

I did it like this:

```
<audio id="myaudio" muted="true" style="display:none">
    <source src="some_audio_source" type="audio/*" /> <!--  -->
</audio>

<button id="fake-btn" style="display: hidden"></button>

<div @mousehover="playAud('myaudio')>
   <img src="some_iamge_source> 
</div>

playAud(audid) {
    document.getElementById('fake-btn').click();
    const curAud = document.getElementById(audid);
    curAud.play();
}
```

However, the error `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first` still persists.

Is there any workaround on these restrictions?

Comment: Duplicate of [How to handle "Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first." on Desktop with Chrome 66?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49930680/how-to-handle-uncaught-in-promise-domexception-play-failed-because-the-use).