# Audio not playing on render - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, audio

I made this component to play an audio file when the page is rendered.

```
class Audio extends Component {

  randomTrack(){
        [...]
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const audioEl = document.getElementsByClassName("audio-element")[0]
    audioEl.play()
  }

  render() {
      var trackname=this.randomTrack();
    return (
      <div>
        <audio className="audio-element">
          <source src={trackname}></source>
        </audio>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default Audio;
```

Each time the browser window reloads after saving changes in code, the audio plays.

BUT if I manually refresh the window OR if I deploy the code to a site and then open the site, it won't play.
I get it has something to do with this error I then get in the console:

> Audio.js:12 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because
> the user didn't interact with the document first.

But then, why does it play when it reloads?
And is it possible to make it play automatically when the page loads, somehow?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49930680/how-to-handle-uncaught-in-promise-domexception-play-failed-because-the-use

Answer (score 0):

You can try it in this way

```
class Audio extends Component {

  randomTrack(){
        [...]
  }

  render() {
    let trackname=this.randomTrack();
    return (
      <div>
        <audio autoplay className="audio-element">
          <source src={trackname}></source>
        </audio>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default Audio;
```

a better way to use a standard solution to play audio.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the problem persists