# Error Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first, how can i solve this?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a game for a school project and want to add music to the login screen. When my page loads, I get the error `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first`.

This is my function to play the audio

```js
function speelmuziek() {
 var audio = new Audio('sounds/waitsound.mp3');
 audio.play()
}
```

And I use this in the body of my page to load the function.

```html
<body onload="speelmuziek()">
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Check this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49930680/how-to-handle-uncaught-in-promise-domexception-play-failed-because-the-use

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to simulate some user iteraction. Like mute audio -> unmute and then play or something like this