# Can't get Tone.js player to work and play a single wav file

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, web-audio-api, tone.js

Having issues to get Tone Player to play anything, here is my simple VueJs code:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Simple Tone.js Demo</h1>
    <button style="background-color: cadetblue; padding: 4px 10px;" @click="play">Play</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import * as Tone from "tone";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      player: null,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    async play() {
      try {
        console.log("Tone.js context state:", Tone.context.state);
        if (Tone.context.state !== "running") {
          await Tone.start();
          console.log("audio context started");
        }
        this.player.start();
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error during playback:", error.message, error);
      }
    },

    async initializePlayer() {
      console.log(Tone.context.state);

      try {
        this.player = await new Tone.Player({
          url: "/sounds/rain.wav",
          loop: true,
          autostart: false,
        }).toDestination();

        this.player.loaded;
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error loading audio file:", error);
      }
      console.log("Audio file loaded", this.player.loaded);
    },
  },
  created() {
    this.initializePlayer();
  },
};
</script>
```

The sound I am loading exists at the correct location sound/rain.wav and browser is able to open it correctly if I enter it's path in chrome
http://localhost:5173/sounds/rain.wav
[image]

output I get from running the app:

[image]

Can somebody knowledgable with Tone.js help me get the Player to play a single file? I've spent whole day on this and even engaged with GPT4 but I got the same issue, Player is unable to play a simple file.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49930680/how-to-handle-uncaught-in-promise-domexception-play-failed-because-the-use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the error happens because the `Player` is not yet done with the download of the audio.

The constructor doesn't return a promise. If you want to wait for the `Player` to be ready you need to pass an `onload` function. It can be used to wait for the `Player` to be ready by wrapping it in a promise.

```
this.player = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const player = new Tone.Player({
        loop: true,
        onerror: (err) => reject(err),
        onload: () => resolve(player),
        url: '/sounds/rain.wav'
    });
});

this.player.toDestination();
```