How to reproduce the same audio
I'm making a simple audio button for the footer of my site. the button itself is working but when I go to another page inside my site it stops playing. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.
The thing is that I add my footer to all my pages with the script...
BTW this is my proper first coding project.
Here's my footer code:


// audio.js

// Get the audio element and button
const audio = document.getElementById("background-audio");
const audioButton = document.getElementById("audio-toggle");

// Add click event listener to toggle playback
audioButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    if (audio.paused) {
        audio.play();
        sessionStorage.setItem("audioPlaying", "true"); // Store the audio playing state
        audioButton.textContent = "||"; // Change the button text to "Pause"
    } else {
        audio.pause();
        sessionStorage.setItem("audioPlaying", "false");
        audioButton.textContent = "▷"; // Change the button text to "Play"
    }
});

// When the page loads, check if the audio was previously playing
if (sessionStorage.getItem("audioPlaying") === "true") {
    audio.play();
    audioButton.textContent = "||"; // Set button text to "Pause"
} else {
    audioButton.textContent = "▷"; // Set button text to "Play"
}

// Save the playback state when leaving the page
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", () => {
    sessionStorage.setItem("audioPlaying", audio.paused ? "false" : "true");
});
/* Footer */
footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: inherit;
    padding: 1rem 2rem;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.6;
    background: #fffff2;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
}

/* Flexbox container for footer content */
.footer-content {
    display: flex; /* Enables flexbox layout */
    justify-content: space-between; /* Space between text and button */
    align-items: center; /* Align items vertically */
    width: 100%; /* Full width of the footer */
    margin-bottom: 4px;
}

/* Footer text */
.footer-text {
    text-align: center; /* Keeps text centered */
    flex-grow: 1; /* Allows the text to take up remaining space */
}

/* Audio button */
.audio-button button {
    margin-left: auto; /* Pushes the button to the right */
    background-color: #4CAF50; /* Green background */
    color: black; /* White text */
    padding: 0.5rem 1rem; /* Button padding */
    border: none; /* Remove borders */
    border-radius: 4px; /* Rounded corners */
    cursor: pointer; /* Pointer cursor on hover */
}

/* Button hover effect */
.audio-button button:hover {
    background-color: #45a049; /* Slightly darker green on hover */
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Footer -->
<footer>
    <div class="horizontallinefooter"></div>
    <div class="footer-content">
        <div class="footer-text">
            It is <span id="time">14:24:24</span> on a <span id="day">Monday</span> in Molelos (PT) right now  
            <span id="activity">the cats sleep</span>
        </div>
        
        <div class="audio-button">
            <!-- Play/Pause button for audio -->
            <button id="audio-toggle" class="favorite styled" type="button">Play</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>

<!-- Hidden audio player for persistent background sound -->
<audio id="background-audio" src="../audio/portugalsound.mp3" loop></audio>

<!-- Include the Clock Script -->
<script src="../clock.js"></script>

  <!-- THE SOUND STOPS WHEN I CLICK A NEW PAGE FROM THE SITE FIX THIS! -->
<!-- Include the Audio Control Script (for Play/Pause functionality) -->
<script src="../audio.js"></script> <!-- Ensure this points to the correct location -->




What do you mean?

It's not everything AI, I was mixing and trying to learn with AI, is that a problem?

Do you see any errors or warnings in your browser devtools inspect facility console? Usually a browser will only play audio as a result of a user interaction. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75786061/unable-to-play-audio-in-browser-without-user-interaction and several other related SO questions.

Thanks @AHaworth! I'll take a look, my only doubt is that if it's possible to make that. Because when I go to another page it reloads so automatically the script itself reloads if that make sense. I guess it could only be like a one page thing, right?

I think you may find yourself creating a one page system, or at least keeping the audio on a constant page.

That's good to know! I really appreciate it :)

JAVA? really???

Adding to previous useful comments, I would suggest you take a good basic course. There are many free ones available online. Forget about AI to start with; it's like trying to fly a plane using autopilot from day one. :-)

@pierpy yeah I'm doing "The Odin Project" but I'm making this site from scratch, I use AI sometimes for concepts, mdn developers, w3 and stack overflow

The interesting thing is that I'm able to read my code and I would be able to do everything that I did by my one so I think is "how do we use AI" and IMO it's a nice combo wit those other platforms. Do you have any course suggestions? @pierpy
