# When using Vite.js with react to load audio, DOMException: Failed to load because no supported source was found (didn't face this with CRA)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node-modules, vite

I'm refactoring a Reactjs app created using CRA to Vite.js. `Fun.jsx`, which plays an audio when it's mounted and stops when unmounted. However, after shifting to Vite, it doesn't play the. There were no issues before vite.

I had to change a couple lines to make vite happy, they are commented:

```
import React, { useEffect, useMemo } from 'react';
import { Hash, Sort, BinaryString } from './FunItems';
import Background from './Background';

// const musicContext = require.context('../assets/music/', false, /\.(aac)$/);
// const musicFiles = musicContext.keys().map(musicContext);

// for vite, use this instead:
const musicContext = import.meta.glob('../assets/music/*.aac');
const musicFiles = Object.keys(musicContext).map(key => musicContext[key]());

export default function Fun() {
  const randomSongIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * musicFiles.length);
  const audio = useMemo(() => new Audio(musicFiles[randomSongIndex]), [randomSongIndex]);

  useEffect(() => {
    audio.loop = true;
    audio.volume = 0.3;

    let playing = audio.play();
    if (playing !== undefined) {
      playing.then(_ => {
      })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    }

    return () => audio.pause();
  }, [audio]);

  return (
    <div>
      <Background />
      <Hash />
      <Sort />
      <BinaryString />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Console shows: `DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first. https : // goo . gl / xX8pDD` (stackoverflow disallows googl links)

Didn't face the above problem before using Vite with the same code, what's the issue?

Comment: Re that error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49930680/how-to-handle-uncaught-in-promise-domexception-play-failed-because-the-use