# Play a video with js without the restriction of user interaction

Tags: javascript, web, dom, google-chrome-extension

Need to play a video element with js from my content-script file of a chrome extension.

The error is:

> DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first.

I have seen other extensions like Youtube Party open a youtube video and playing directly without me having to do an interaction with the page. Reviewing his source code they are just doing `videoHtmlElement.play()` like me, but for them it works, what can I do to avoid the DOMException?

My code is:

```
case "syncVideoState":
  const {time, paused} = msg.currentVideoState;
  item.currentTime = time;
  if(!paused){
    item.play();
  } else {
    item.pause();
  }
  sendResponse(true);
  break;
```

Comment: Note that Chrome uses media engagement heuristics to allow non-muted autoplay depending on the site, so youtube is allowed because of that.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because of a relatively new browser policy which prevents **audio** sources from playing without the user interacting with the page first.

The easiest way to "avoid" this problem is by calling `item.muted = true;` before playing the video.

Please have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49930680/how-to-handle-uncaught-in-promise-domexception-play-failed-because-the-use?rq=2) for more info about it.